# creation ERC721 error: Transaction failed, invalid address,

Tags: tokens, erc-721

I would like to learn how ERC721 token works. I found some sample contracts online and tried to use remix and Ethereum Wallet to deploy the contract. The compile was fine but failed in the creation.
The error message on remix is

> "creation ERC721 error: Transaction failed, invalid address. If you
>   use an injected provider, please check it is properly unlocked".

Can anyone help me? what can I do to fix the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Seems it's not getting the address from where to deploy the contract. Please ensure the chosen environment (Javascript VM, Injected Web3, Or Web3 Provider) is chosen properly, and the address chosen from them have enough some Ether balance to deploy the contract.

Comment: I finally found the answer from this post https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2806.
Now my test ERC721 token contract was deployed.  https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xfaa830fa15d5df42ee8c936c50a546687c951bda

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example for a fully functioning ERC-721 implementation:

https://github.com/fulldecent/su-squares-bounty

Answer (score 1):

I believe Open Zeppelin's ERC721 explanation was one of the most useful article i read about the protocol.

Check out the erc721 protocol **Open Zeppelin's API section** which explains every aspect of the functions related to the token.

Don't forget to try out Open Zeppelin's Wizard to create your first erc721 smart contract without much effort and it works perfectly. There is also an **Open In Remix** which is very helpful in my experience. :>

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc721 
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721 
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard